# How to change date and time of SQL Server independent as windows same as nls_calendar in oracle?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-server-2012, instance

I need to change date and time in sql server instance without and independent change windows date/time.
I can change date and time of oracle by nls_calendar command. Exists anyway to change this???

Comment: Have anyone solution to this problem???

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. It is tied to OS date ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)).

But you can use a custom date function which will take a delta value and return GETDATE() + delta. If your code is going to be in production environment and would have to fallback to the real deal, then add another flag to the input (T for test and P for prod or something like that) and return GETDATE() when its production.